# Processing scroll event ListView (Win32 API)

Tags: listview, winapi, events, scroll

I have read many topics, but I can't find an answer:

How can I process scroll events from a ListView?

I tried processing `LVM_SCROLL`, `WM_VSCROLL` and `WM_SYSCOMMAND`. But, I don't received these messages in my `WinMainProc()` and `WndProc()` functions when I scroll the ListView.

I need to process these events to modify the coordinates of an Edit component. I create the Edit in `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` for changing the text fields of the ListView. If the Edit was already create, and I scroll the ListView, the Edit component has the wrong coordinates.

```
program WinApi;

{$APPTYPE GUI}
{$MODE OBJFPC}

{$R Resource.rc}

uses
  Windows, Messages, commdlg;

const
  //
  idListView = 1025;

var
  //
  WndMsg: MSG;
  //
  MainWndDestroy: Boolean;
  //
  hMainWnd, hListViewWnd: HWND;

//
procedure InitCommonControls; external 'comctl32.dll' name 'InitCommonControls';

//
function MainWndProc(Wnd: HWND; uMsg: Integer; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; Stdcall; forward;

procedure CreateListView;
var
  //
  lc: LV_COLUMN;
  //
  lvi: LV_ITEM;
begin
  //
  hListViewWnd:=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, WC_LISTVIEW, '', WS_VISIBLE or WS_CHILD or LVS_REPORT or LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS, 8, 8, 264, 96, hMainWnd, idListView, 0, nil);

  //
  lc.mask:=LVCF_FMT or LVCF_TEXT or LVCF_WIDTH;
  //
  lc.fmt:=LVCFMT_LEFT;
  //
  lc.iSubItem:=0; lc.cx:=130;
  //
  lc.pszText:='Params';
  //
  SendMessage(hListViewWnd, LVM_INSERTCOLUMN, 0, lParam(@lc));

  //
  lc.pszText:='Values';
  //
  SendMessage(hListViewWnd, LVM_INSERTCOLUMN, 1, lParam(@lc));

  //
  lvi.mask:=LVIF_STATE or LVIF_TEXT;
  //
  lvi.state:=0;
  //
  lvi.stateMask:=0;
  //
  lvi.iItem:=0;
  //
  lvi.iSubItem:=0;
  //
  lvi.pszText:='Param #0';
  //
  lvi.cchTextMax:=8;
  //
  SendMessage(hListViewWnd, LVM_INSERTITEM, 0, LPARAM(@lvi));

  //
  lvi.iItem:=1;
  //
  lvi.pszText:='Param #1';
  //
  SendMessage(hListViewWnd, LVM_INSERTITEM, 0, LPARAM(@lvi));

  //
  lvi.iItem:=2;
  //
  lvi.pszText:='Param #2';
  //
  SendMessage(hListViewWnd, LVM_INSERTITEM, 0, LPARAM(@lvi));

  //
  lvi.iItem:=3;
  //
  lvi.pszText:='Param #3';
  //
  SendMessage(hListViewWnd, LVM_INSERTITEM, 0, LPARAM(@lvi));

  //
  lvi.iItem:=4;
  //
  lvi.pszText:='Param #4';
  //
  SendMessage(hListViewWnd, LVM_INSERTITEM, 0, LPARAM(@lvi));

  //
  lvi.iItem:=5;
  //
  lvi.pszText:='Param #5';
  //
  SendMessage(hListViewWnd, LVM_INSERTITEM, 0, LPARAM(@lvi));

  //
  ListView_SetItemText(hListViewWnd, 0, 1, 'Value #1');
end;

function MainWndCreate: Boolean;
var
  //
  ClassEx: TWndClassEx;
begin
  //
  Result:=False;

  //
  ClassEx.cbSize:=SizeOf(ClassEx);
  //
  ClassEx.style:=CS_DBLCLKS or CS_OWNDC;
  //
  ClassEx.lpfnWndProc:=WndProc(@MainWndProc);
  //
  ClassEx.cbClsExtra:=0;
  //
  ClassEx.cbWndExtra:=0;
  //
  ClassEx.hInstance:=HInstance;
  //
  ClassEx.hIconSm:=LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
  //
  ClassEx.hIcon:=LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
  //
  ClassEx.hCursor:=LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
  //
  ClassEx.hbrBackground:=CreateSolidBrush($d8e9ec);
  //
  ClassEx.lpszMenuName:=nil;
  //
  ClassEx.lpszClassName:='WinApiWnd';

  //
  if RegisterClassEx(ClassEx) = 0 then Exit;

  //
  hMainWnd:=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, 'WinApiWnd', 'WinApi', WS_DLGFRAME or WS_SYSMENU, 100, 100, 640, 480, GetDesktopWindow, 0, HInstance, nil);

  //
  if hMainWnd = 0 then Exit;

  //
  InitCommonControls;

  //
  CreateListView;

  //
  ShowWindow(hMainWnd, SW_SHOW);
  //
  UpdateWindow(hMainWnd);
  //
  Result:=True;
end;

function MainWndProc(Wnd: HWND; uMsg: Integer; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; Stdcall;
begin
  //
  if Wnd = hMainWnd then
    //
    if uMsg = WM_DESTROY then
      //
      MainWndDestroy:=True;

  //
  if uMsg = WM_VSCROLL then
    //
    MessageBox(0, 'WM_VSCROLL', '', 0);

  //
  if uMsg = LVM_SCROLL then
    //
    MessageBox(0, 'LVM_VSCROLL', '', 0);

  //
  Result:=DefWindowProc(Wnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
end;

begin
  //
  MainWndDestroy:=False;

  //
  ZeroMemory(@WndMsg, SizeOf(WndMsg));

  //
  if MainWndCreate then
    //
    while GetMessage(WndMsg, 0, 0, 0) do
    begin
      //
      TranslateMessage(WndMsg);
      //
      DispatchMessage(WndMsg);

      //
      if MainWndDestroy then Exit;
    end;
end.
```

Decision (by **Remy Lebeau**):

> ... ListView does send LVN_BEGINSCROLL and LVN_ENDSCROLL notification
>   messages to its parent window, so those messages will appear in
>   MainWndProc()

I defined:
    LVN_BEGINSCROLL = 4294967116;
Because it is defined incorrectly in Lazarus.

And add code in `MainWndProc`:
...

```
//
if uMsg = WM_NOTIFY then
  begin
//
pnm:=PNMHDR(lPrm);

//
if pnm^.code = LVN_BEGINSCROLL then
//
SetWindowText(hMainWnd, 'LVN_BEGINSCROLL');
  end;
```

And this worked...

Comment: You will get a WM_VSCROLL message in the parent's window procedure. Post repro code if you can't make it work.

Comment: I added code with a breakpoint: if Msg = WM_VSCROLL ... But WM_VSCROLL have not received in WndProc.

Comment: I don't know how you expect me to debug code that I cannot see. Post a [mcve].

Comment: @Alexan-Dwer: "Msg = WM_VSCROLL" this is assignment.

Comment: I can add Pascal code, it is convenient for you? Or convert code to C++?

Comment: @user2120666: "Msg = WM_VSCROLL" in C style "this is assignment", in Pascal this comparison.

Comment: Any code is better than nothing.

Comment: @user2120666 I added code.

Comment: @Cody Gray I added example source and full code.

Comment: @CodyGray In MainWndProc I use `Wnd = hMainWnd` only for `WM_DESTROY`. I do not limit `WM_VSCROLL` by `Wnd`, if any `WM_VSCROLL` will be received, that to show `MessageBox`.

Comment: Right, sorry. I was just pretending that I could read Pascal.

Comment: Upvote question, because code was added. This is sign of interest.

Comment: @user2120666, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`LVM_SCROLL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761151.aspx) is not a notification message, so it will not appear in `MainWndProc()`. You send that message to a ListView when you want to manually scroll it in code.  However, a ListView does send [`LVN_BEGINSCROLL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774802(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`LVN_ENDSCROLL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774816.aspx) notification messages to its parent window, so those messages will appear in `MainWndProc()`.

[`WM_VSCROLL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787577.aspx) is not a notification message, so it will not appear in `MainWndProc()`, either. In order to receive `WM_VSCROLL` messages for the ListView, you would need to subclass the ListView itself, using either [`SetWindowLongPtr(GWL_WNDPROC)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898.aspx) or [`SetWindowSubclass()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102.aspx).

That being said, you don't need to embed a separate `EDIT` control on top of a ListView in order to edit the ListView's items.  A ListView has a built-in editor for that very purpose (see [`LVM_EDITLABEL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774898.aspx)).  Just note that in report mode, the built-in editor edits data in the first column only, but you can manipulate the editor directly to allow editing data in other columns.  I wrote the following code to handle that issue using `TListView` in Delphi, but you can adapt it to work with plain Win32 API instead:

[How to use the Build-in Editor of TListView to Edit SubItems](http://codecentral.embarcadero.com/Item/23873)

Comment: I try process `LVN_BEGINSCROLL` in `WM_NOTIFY`, it did not work. After, I add `SetWindowLong` for `hListViewWnd` with `GWL_WNDPROC` and `ListViewProc`. In `ListViewProc` I add `if uMsg = WM_VSCROLL then MessageBox(0, 'WM_VSCROLL', '', 0);`, but this did not work, too.

Comment: They both work fine for me. You must be doing something wrong. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41266221/edit) to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve) of your latest code.

Comment: On your advice, I was able to get a decision from `LVN_BEGINSKROLL`. Thanks you!